# Cakephp calling a function between Model and View

Tags: php, cakephp, separation-of-concerns

Let say i have a function:

```
function getCarName() {
   return array(1 => 'BMW', 2 => 'MERCEDEZ BENZ', 3 => 'RENAULT');
}
```

I will use this function on both model and view, should i create two same function on AppHelper and Car Model? What is correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You would want to keep it DRY (dont repeat yourself). Therefore your approach will not work.
Either make it a normal model method and use the controller to pass it down.
Or use static model methods you can access similar to this approach:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/ - It seems like you got here some enum like array - which you also might want to work with in your forms etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having two functions doing the same thing is usually a bad idea as it violates the [don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Instead, I would add the function to your `Car` model and then pass the data from your controller(s) to your view(s) with something like:

```
$this->set('carNames', $this->Car->getCarNames());
```

The car names are then available in the view via the `$carNames` variable.